# Excel - Divide a value by N, divide remainder by Y and combine both results to get a total

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a supplier who offers us a promotional rate on Nail Guns based on quantities of nails purchased.

For every 50 boxes of nails, we get 1x Nail Guns at promotional rate.
For every 90 boxes of nails, we get 2x Nail Guns at promotional rate.

Let's say I have an order for 894 boxes.

Currently, I first divide this number by 90 to get a quotient of 9 and a remainder of 84. This quotient gets multiplied by two to give me a value of **18** (90 boxes = 2x guns)
The remainder is less than 90, but ≥ 50, so I add an extra gun. to give me a total of **19** guns.

Essentially, I need an Excel formula that first calculates the quotient of my number of boxes using a divisor of 90, multiplies that quotient by two, then calculates the quotient of the remainder using a divisor of 50 and adds that result to the first value to give me a total number of guns that qualify for promotional rate.

Ta!

Answer (score 2):

`=INT(894/90)*2+(MOD(894,90)>=50)`

or

```
=LET(value,    894,
     divider1, 90,
     divider2, 50,
INT(value/divider1)*2+(MOD(value,divider1)>=divider2))
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I noticed that your formula was missing the multiplier for the lots of 90 but `=(INT(K894/90))*2+(MOD(894,90)>50)` seems to fix it. Much appreciated

Comment: I also changed `>` to `>=` because if the remainder equals 50 it should return 1.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.